# sufficient and necessary conditions for compactness of a subspace

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have difficulty understanding part of the proof given in Munkres' book for Lemma 26.1:

> Let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$. Then $Y$ is compact if and only if every
> covering of $Y$ by sets open in $X$ contains a finite subcollection covering $Y$.

In the second direction of the proof, we start off with a covering $\{A'_{\alpha}\}$ of $Y$ by sets open in $Y$. That is, $\bigcup A'_{\alpha}= Y.$ Then, since $Y$ has its subspace topology, we can always find a collection $\{A_{\alpha}\}$ of sets open in $X$ such that $A'_\alpha = A_{\alpha} \cap Y$. The author then claims that this collection is a covering of $Y$ by sets open in $X$. <s>That is, we'd get</s>  $$\bigcup A_{\alpha}= Y.$$
But I cannot see this. To me, it's clear that $\bigcup A_{\alpha} \cap Y = Y$ yields $Y \subseteq 
\bigcup A_{\alpha} $, but I cannot conclude the reverse relation. How do we get that $\bigcup A_{\alpha} \subseteq Y$, as well? (See the highlighted part in the attached image.)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not require equality at all. $Y \subseteq \cup_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}$. By hypothesis this implies that there is a finite sub-cover, say $Y \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{\alpha_i}$. Then we also have $Y \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{\alpha_i}'$ (because if  a point in $Y$ belongs to $A_{\alpha}$ then it belongs to $A_{\alpha'}$). We have obtained  a finite subcover and the proof is over.